# ioncube require an include key

Tags: php, ioncube

ioncube encoder has an option to "require an include key". This feature adds a random string in each encoded file, so if encoded file requires/includes another file (let's say encoded file index.php includes encoded file include_me.php), user can't replace include_me.php with his own file, or the script won't work (error will be displayed).

That sounds like a nice security option, but how do I make "real-life" scripts using this option? All the modern scripts require/include config file(s), and config file is automatically generated when user runs an installer. Put simply, how can I use "require an include key" option and have an unencoded config file included in script?

Otherwise, this feature doesn't make any sense to me (unless script has no config file, or config file is also encoded, which would require script developer to make a custom config file for every user with his database credentials).

Answer (score 2):

I know, been too long you have created this question but maybe that can help others. I had the same problem.

You have to include your script in a bridge file and you have to include that bridge file to your first encoded file.

[Here is how](http://blog.ioncube.com/2014/12/15/mixing-encoded-unencoded-files/)